# Constrain two column TableLayout with stretchColumns

Tags: tablelayout, android

I have this layout,

```
    <TableLayout android:stretchColumns="0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow>
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/StationTextView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:completionThreshold="2"
                    android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionSearch" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/ShowTimesButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_btn_search" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

from the start everything is as I want it to be, e.g. the textview takes upp all space that the button does not take. But if the textview gets filled with a long string it pushes the button off the screen, I want the layout to be constraind within the screen and never push things off the screen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try use weight in your layout:

```
<TableLayout android:stretchColumns="0" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/StationTextView" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:completionThreshold="2" 
                                android:inputType="textAutoComplete" 
                                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionSearch" 
                                android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/ShowTimesButton" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_btn_search" 
                android:layout_weight="0" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```